# Confused about git merge, how to merge master into branch but keep branches seperate

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I've seen git merge name, git merge master name, and git merge. I'm confused what each command is doing.

Correct me if I'm wrong, does it matter which branch you're checked out at the time when you're merging, it seems it does.

Just to be sure I understand, tell me...

How can I merge branch a and branch b into one? What would new branch be a or b, how do you decide..

How can I merge branch a into master so its new master? (i.e. default merging)

How can I merge master to branch a so new changes in master are now present in branch a but they are still separate meaning if I commit on master it doesn't extend branch a?

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Does it matter which branch you're in at the time of merging?"
Yes, it does.

"How can I merge branch a and branch b into one?"

If you want to merge your changes in branch b onto branch a, you should checkout to (`git checkout branch_a`) and then do `git merge branch_b`
You will then be in branch_a and your changes in branch_b will be merged on to branch_a. (Note that your changes in branch_a will not be reflected in branch_b).

"How do I decide?"

For example, if you want to merge your feature branch (say, branch_a) changes on to your local master branch, you should checkout to master branch and merge branch_a by the method I have mentioned above.

"How do I merge my master branch changes onto a new branch?"

Say you have to merge your master branch changes on to branch_new, you should first pull your remote branch changes on to your local master using

```
git pull <remote_name> master:master
```

and then checkout to your new_branch using

```
git checkout new_branch
```

Then, you need to merge using

```
git merge master
```

Comment: after i merge branch a into b. Then if i checkout b and commit, will it show up as new commit for b only? or both. And basically merging never actually merges branches into one. It just copies changes from other branch minus conflicts into checked out branch and make new commit if it's not fastforward, correct?

Comment: Yes, when you commit, it will only show up in that current branch. And yes, when you merge one branch onto another, the changes on the other branches are reflected on the current branch while retaining the merged branch. If its not fast-forward, it makes a new commit with a default Merge Conflict message.

Comment: I added picture to show what's been confusing me. From your answer i get that to merge branch A into master i checkout into master and then do `git merge branchA`, however, from where i am learning they are doing everything same upto command. which is `git merge master branchA`

Comment: In that picture, it shows that you're already in the master branch. So you just need to do `git merge coins`. Also please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: is there no difference between `git merge coins` vs `git merge master coins`.

Comment: Thanks, i feel i am really close to getting it... In my mind everything makes sense if i ignore this. But it is there

Comment: even in fast forward branch is copied not really merged into one.

Comment: In your case there is no difference between `git merge coins` and `git merge master coins` as the `master` branch is already updated. But in case your `master` branch was not updated, `git merge master coins` will merge your changes in `master` and `coins` branch into the branch that you are currently in.